# MetroDialogBox.Show method doesn't exist

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, metroframework

MetroFramework.Forms.MetroMessageBox does not have a Show() method. Using VS2017 Community, have installed MetroFramework with NuGet and referenced the Metro DLLs in my solution. have

```
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
```

in the Forms cs file. I am trying to do

```
MetroFramework.Forms.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Your message here.", "Title Here", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
```

but Show is illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MetroFramework.Forms.MetroMessageBox.Show(
```

should be either:

```
MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox(
```

or:

```
MetroMessageBox(
```

based on similar looking code at http://foxlearn.com/article/metro-message-box-in-csharp-124.html and the fact that `MetroMessageBox` is in the [`MetroFramework`](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/blob/master/MetroFramework/MessageBox/MetroMessageBox.cs) namespae.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried those. It seems the problem was I needed to get the package MetroModernUI rather than the MetroModern I had. I realised there were a bunch of controls eg DateTime, Trackbar that weren't in the Toolbox. Now have the proper Neget package and the MessageBox - including your code mjwills - now work.